# Horizontal Bar Graph in HTML CANVAS 5 without library

Tags: typescript, canvas, graph, html5-canvas, bar-chart

I am trying to make dynamic horizontal bar graph, with dynamic width ,when I change canvas width and height , it adjust the position of horizontal bars accordingly.(Canvas HTML5) without any library.
I calculate dynamic step size by that for both x-axis and y-axis

```
    // Y-axis label
    var labelonYaxis = 4;
    var StepSizeY = 1;
    for (let index = 0; index < StepSizeOptions.length; index++) {
      var TotalSteps = this.RangeX / StepSizeOptions[index];
      if (TotalSteps <= labelonYaxis) {
        StepSizeY = StepSizeOptions[index];
        break;
      }
       this.SampleLayerContext.fillText(currentY, this.marginLeft / 2, (this.gridHeight + this.marginTop) 
 - y);
```

Unable to find solution to find dynamic height and position of horizontal bar on yaxis  formula
The formula I made so far

```js
    var barWidth = this.data.length / this.gridWidth;
    var pixel = (this.gridWidth / this.RangeX);
    this.SampleLayerContext.rect(this.marginLeft, this.gridHeight-Yaxis, Yaxis, barWidth);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't sure if this is what you wait. But you can calculate the h with the height of you window. Use a factor to multiply H if you don't wait a bar with full height. Example: H*0.8 //80%.

To calculare y axis you need know the bar' height and subtract this of y bases.

```js
pintGraph = function( bars ){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,W,H);  
  barw = canvas.width / (bars.length) - marginbar;
  
  for(let i = 0; i < bars.length; i++){
    ctx.fillStyle = color[i];
    barh =  H * (bars[i]/max);
  
    ctx.fillRect( i * (barw + marginbar), Hbase - barh, barw , barh);
    
  }
}
```

Look my project to understand: https://codepen.io/Luis4raujo/full/ZEBaVbJ

If this help you check as correct or voteup.